# How to make questions displayed one-by-one after answered and clicked to Play button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input-field

I am new in Unity, and try to make questions displayed one-by-one after answered and clicked to the Play button

```
public class PlayGame : MonoBehaviour
{
 
    public string[] questions = {"What is 10+10", "What is 20+20", "What is 30+30", "What is 40+40", "What is 50+50"};
    public string[] correctAnswer = {"20", "40", "60", "80" , "100"};

    public Text question;
    public InputField answer;
    public int selection;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
     question.text = questions[selection];      
    }


    public void CheckAnswer()
    {
        if (answer.text == correctAnswer.ToString())            
        {
            Debug.Log("Answer is Correct");
         //display next question
            
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Answer is not Correct");
            //display next question
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A simple way in this case is to use your ```selection``` variable to keep track of the current question displayed. Then inside your ```CheckAnswer``` method, simply increment ```selection``` by one then update the text just like in your ```Start``` method. If you want to change the question if the answer is correct, then do the increment inside the answer check if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be quite straight forward

```
private int selection = -1;

void Start()
{
    ShowNextQuestion();     
}

private void ShowNextQuestion()
{
    selection++;
    if(selection >= questions.Length - 1) 
    {
        // You said you wanted to restart the questions so simply do
        selection = 0;
    }

    question.text = questions[selection];
}

public void CheckAnswer()
{
    if (answer.text.Equas(correctAnswer[selection]))            
    {
        Debug.Log("Answer is Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Answer is not Correct");
    }

    ShowNextQuestion();
}
```

---

Let me tell you though that in general it's not a good idea to store questions and answers in two individual arrays.

- You can't really be sure that both individual arrays always have te same length
- you have double work when adding or removing a question in the middle
- Imagine later wanting to randomize the order of questions .. you lose track which answer belongs to which question

So I would suggest you rather couple them strong together in a type like

```
[Serializable]
public class Question
{
    // Allow to edit these in the Inspector but nowhere else
    [SerializeField] private string _text;
    [SerializeField] private string _answer;

    // Other classes may only read these
    public string Text => _text;
    public string Answer => _answer;

    // Constructor 
    public Question(string text, string answer)
    {
        _text = text;
        _answer = answer;
    }
}
```

And now in your Component you rather set them via the Inspector or initialize them via

```
public Question[] questions = {
    new Question("What is 10+10", "20"),
    new Question("What is 20+20", "40"),
    new Question("What is 30+30", "60"),
    new Question("What is 40+40", "80"),
    new Question("What is 50+50", "100")
};
```

Then of course you change the code accordingly to access these

```
private void ShowNextQuestion()
{
    selection++;
    if(selection >= questions.Length - 1) 
    {
        // You said you wanted to restart the questions so simply do
        selection = 0;
    }

    question.text = questions[selection].Text;
}

public void CheckAnswer()
{
    if (answer.text.Equals(questions[selection].Answer))           
    {
        Debug.Log("Answer is Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Answer is not Correct");
    }

    ShowNextQuestion();
}
```

Now as said this allows also to give your app a bit randomness by shuffling the questions before starting:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void Start()
{
    questions = questions.OrderBy(q => Random.value).ToArray();

    ShowNextQuestion();
}

private void ShowNextQuestion()
{
    selection++;
    if(selection >= questions.Length - 1) 
    {
        // You said you wanted to restart the questions so simply do
        selection = 0;
        questions = questions.OrderBy(q => Random.value).ToArray();
    }

    question.text = questions[selection].Text;
}
```

Comment: Finally, your 2nd option is the Best! Thanks for helping. Work! I appreciate

Comment: Hi @derHugo After displaying all the questions, I'd want the questions to be displayed again. Help Please! –

Comment: @TanguyMP instead of `Debug.LogWarning("Reached end of questions!", this); return;` simply shuffle the questions again and reset the `selection = 0;`

Comment: @TanguyMP updated it into the answer for all three snippets